# How Retrieve JSON DATA using Where Condition In PRESTO?

Tags: sql, json, presto, presto-jdbc

```
WITH dataset AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (JSON '{"name": "Bob Smith", "org": "legal"}'),
    (JSON '{"name": "Susan Smith", "org": "engineering"}'),
    (JSON '{"name": "Jane Smith", "org": "finance"}')
  ) AS t (users)
)
SELECT json_extract_scalar(users, '$.name') AS user
FROM dataset
```

I want use a condition in this query  Like
Where 'org' =  'legal' How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_extract_scalar` in the where:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(users) AS (VALUES
    (JSON '{"name": "Bob Smith", "org": "legal"}'),
    (JSON '{"name": "Susan Smith", "org": "engineering"}'),
    (JSON '{"name": "Jane Smith", "org": "finance"}')
)

-- query
SELECT json_extract_scalar(users, '$.name') AS user
FROM dataset
WHERE json_extract_scalar(users, '$.org') = 'legal';
```

Output:

| user |
| --- |
| Bob Smith |